# Issues with MySQL and quotation marks

Tags: mysql

I have this very simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM "orders" WHERE "printer_id" = 'AC001' AND "sent" = '0'
```

It throws the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"orders" WHERE "printer_id" = 'AC001' AND "sent" = '0' at line 1
```

Removing the "" from the column names makes it work! Im using Medoo (http://medoo.in/) as my database framework if that helps.

Comment: Issue solved. There was an issue with the frame work that I fixed!

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes around identifiers are used only if the `SQL_MODE` setting includes `ANSI_QUOTES`.

The default identifier quote character is the backtick character.

---

MySQL is returning a syntax error because it's seeing `"orders"` as a string literal, where it's expecting an identifier (a table name).

---

Either of these should work to get around the problem:

Leave the identifiers unquoted:

```
SELECT * FROM  orders  WHERE  printer_id  = 'AC001' AND  sent  = '0'
```

Use backticks to enclose the identifiers

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `printer_id` = 'AC001' AND `sent` = '0'
```

Or (I dom't recommend this, but it is another approach...

Change the setting of the `SQL_MODE` to include `ANSI_QUOTES` option, and use the double quotes as the identifier escape character, like in your original statement.

Answer (score 1):

Fields need to be escaped using backticks, not double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `printer_id` = 'AC001' AND `sent` = '0'
```